# Next.js On-Demand Revalidation from server side (express)

Tags: express, next.js, incremental-static-regeneration

I would like to know what is the best way to revalidate on-demand specific static pages from my server side (express), in my case it's after having created/updated/deleted a category.

I know that according to [Next documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation) I have to create a file : ***client/pages/api/revalidate.js*** that will handle it.
But have I to call it from my express server-side (categoryController.js) :

```
  try {
    await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/revalidate?secret=${process.env.REVALIDATE_TOKEN}`
    );
    console.log("successfully revalidated");
    res.status(200).json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
```

Or is there another proper way to do that ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: You have to call the API route you created in the Next.js app to handle the revalidation. There's no other way currently.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to turn it into production mode and check if things are still working